# Big Endian and Little Endian

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, endianness, mips32

Given is the snap shot of memory of a byte-addressable computer. What would be loaded into register `$16` after execution of instruction `lw $16, 24($17)` if machine is big endian and when Little Endian. Register `$17` contains `200`.

[image]

Now according to me, four bytes would be copied from the memory `(224-227)` irrespective of Little Endian or Big Endian,then if the machine is Big Endian then they will be copied to the register as they are.

If the machine is Little Endian then will be reversed and then copied to the register.

Please guide me if I am wrong with the concept.

Comment: Basically, you are right. I don't know mips enough, however, to know there isn't a catch.

Comment: Big/little endianness has nothing to do with MIPS. So he's just plain right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right.

More technically, in big-endian mode, the most significant byte is the one with the lowest address, and least significant byte is the one with the highest address. In little-endian mode, the most significant byte is the one with the highest address, while the least significant byte is the one with the lowest address.

So the contents of $16 register would be

If big-endian -> BADADBBD
If little-endian -> BDDBDABA

Comment: Yes I really confused byte order in memory and bit patterns in registers which are not related. The bit patterns in registers for the same number will be the same in both architectures.

Comment: No, byte order in memory and registers is the same.

Comment: Just to clarify, in either case, the four bytes from `224` to `227` would be loaded in `$16`; if the architecture is little-endian to begin with, the numbering of OP's memory diagram would have been reversed, therefore giving us `BDDBDABA` instead of `BADADBBD`